# Cache mysql queries in variable and available for every request

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I just started to maintain a browser-game and optimize its code. I can see some functions run more than hundred times. I thought about how to optimize the code.

1- Modify whole platform of programming of the game. (it doesn't make sense because it needs at least 9 months to modify it. Also maybe cause of unexpected bugs and I don't want to get in the way).

2- Working on caching for more efficiency.

I am going to use second way. For more clarifying I put a function of the game here.

```
function modifyResource($vid, $wood, $clay, $iron, $crop, $mode) {

    if($wood<0)$wood=0;
    if($clay<0)$clay=0;
    if($iron<0)$iron=0;
    //if($crop<0)$crop=0;

    $q = "SELECT * from " . TB_PREFIX . "vdata where wref = $vid";
    $result = $this->query($q,__FILE__,__LINE__);
    $res=$this->mysql_fetch_all($result);

    if($wood+$res[0]['wood']>$res[0]['maxstore'] && $mode)$wood=$res[0]['maxstore']-$res[0]['wood'];
    if($clay+$res[0]['clay']>$res[0]['maxstore'] && $mode)$clay=$res[0]['maxstore']-$res[0]['clay'];
    if($iron+$res[0]['iron']>$res[0]['maxstore'] && $mode)$iron=$res[0]['maxstore']-$res[0]['iron'];
    if($crop+$res[0]['crop']>$res[0]['maxcrop'] && $mode)$crop=$res[0]['maxcrop']-$res[0]['crop'];

    if($res[0]['wood']<$wood && !$mode)$wood=$res[0]['wood'];
    if($res[0]['clay']<$clay && !$mode)$clay=$res[0]['clay'];
    if($res[0]['iron']<$iron && !$mode)$iron=$res[0]['iron'];
    if($res[0]['crop']<$crop && !$mode)$crop=$res[0]['crop'];

    if(!$mode) {
        $wood = -$wood;
        $clay = -$clay;
        $iron = -$iron;
        $crop = -$crop;
    }
    $q = "UPDATE " . TB_PREFIX . "vdata set wood = wood + $wood, clay = clay + $clay, iron = iron + $iron, crop = crop + $crop where wref = $vid";
    $r = $this->query($q,__FILE__,__LINE__);
    if($r){
        // $this->logging->addResourceLog($vid, $wood, $clay, $iron, $crop, $log);
    }
    return true;
}
```

As you can see the function select vdata table to get necessary information then modify it and finally update the table. two queries run in this function. vdata is a real big table for example in the case is more than 500MB for 80,000 rows. The function runs 88 times for every request from user. This means 88 times a big table Selected and Updated. it costs very much hardware resources and also raise loading time.

An Idea is crossed my mind, Store select query in a variable then update it If function run for the first time. And for other times only update the variable until the class of database destroyed then apply all changes. this will cause save 2x87 queries.

**Note:**
this caching in variable only persistent until user request accomplished. then destroy all stored(cached) data.

This is just an idea, I have no idea how it can be functioning, Or would be useful if I coded it. Or is there any alternative way or any suggested plugins or class that have same functioning?

Therefore my question has three parts:

1- Would be this idea useful?

2- if yes! Is there any class or plugin that I use it or get more idea?

3- if no! What will be your suggestion to optimze the game?

Comment: How did you reach the 9 month time frame to fix performance issues? How can you know that your caching solution will not introduce bugs? (In any case, using variables to store information fetched from DB is a fairly basic approach, you should probably do it no matter what other fixes you do.)

Comment: Because I follow trace in the whole scripts, and no way to remove them or replaced for example whenever updated there are some functions after that read latest modification of table, hence in order to resort them, I prefer to write a code for my own, not to re-build it.